# Fix boundary effects with geom_circle

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I use geom_circle to to generate some circle. If in addition I set limits with xlim or ylim, the circles change.

```r
library(ggforce) # for circles
library(gridExtra)

x <- seq(-2,2,by=4)
grid <- expand.grid(x,x)
df = data.frame(x=grid[,1],y=grid[,2], r = rep(4,nrow(grid)))

p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, r = r), data = df) +coord_fixed()


p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, r = r), data = df) +coord_fixed()+
  xlim(-2,2) +   ylim(-2,2)

grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

I would hope to get the restriction of the plot p1 to the region specified by xlim and ylim

Comment: use `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-2,2), ylim = c(-2,2))`, instead of just `xlim(-2,2) +   ylim(-2,2)`